# Union within CTE removing records but there are no Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with a union within a CTE in oracle.  I am trying to get the sum of a field called P in our database and was checking to make sure the value was accurate as I was writing my view.  I found oracle treating these queries in an unusual way after adding a union

```
with CTE_A as 
(select  P, 'full' as coverage from Table_A), 

CTE_B as
(select  P, 'partial' as coverage from Table_A)
```

Here if I `select sum(P) from CTE_A` I get 100. However, if i do the following:

```
CTE_C as 
(select P, coverage from CTE_A

union 

select P, coverage from CTE_B)

select sum(P) from CTE_C where coverage='full'
```

I get 78.

When I use union All I get 100 again.  I know that union removes duplicates but there should be no duplicates within CTE_A and CTE_B since I am declaring the field coverage.

Comment: UNION removes **all** duplicates, including those that already exist in each operand (table) - not just those that are duplicates *between* the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UNION` is removing duplicates from the result set.  You must have something like this in CTE_A:

```
22 | Full
22 | Full
```

Which, when you `SUM()` CTE_A, both are counted.  But after you `UNION`, you will only have one record, lowering the `SUM()` total from CTE_C to 78 (`100-22=78`).

`UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates, which is why this doesn't happen when you include `ALL`.

Comment: Oh duh! That makes sense...Thank you so much it was driving me nuts.

Comment: @Magnolia - if this is the answer (it 100% is), you should mark the answer as "Correct". (Unless - I don't remember that - perhaps if you are a brand-new user, you are only allowed to do that after 24 hours? If so please do make a note to come back and mark the answer that way.)